# Binding More Than One Dynamically Added Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile and I need to bind some tap events to dynamically added content. It seems that the way I am doing it, my code only runs the last element I attach a tap event to inside my code. For example, this code will **not** alert "Hi" when I click on element A but **it will** alert "Bye" when I click on element B.

I'm sure this is a simple mistake but I've been banging my head against the desk trying to figure it out.

```
$(document).off("tap").on("tap", "#A", function() {
    alert('Hi');
});

$(document).off("tap").on("tap", "#B", function () {
    alert('Bye');
});
```

Comment: Does an element of ID `A` exist?

Comment: Yes. If I switch their order in the code A will work and B will not.

Comment: `.off('tap', '#a, #b').on('tap', '#a, #b', function ()` try this.

Comment: Why do you need to unbind event?

Comment: @Omar I like that method. Is it still possible for me to access the elements with a $(this) somehow? I'm trying to find a more standardized way of doing this.

Comment: Yes it's possible, it depends how you bind events after elements are created or during creation. `$(this).off('tap').on('tap', function`.

Comment: @Omar I think I'm binding them after they are created.

Comment: In this case, can u post how u create them?

Comment: @Omar, I guess I'm not sure what you mean. I'm adding these elements in with an append()

Comment: For example `$('<div/>', { id:'A' }).on('tap', function () { // code }).appendTo('#target');`.

Comment: $(document).on("tap", ".add", function () {
  $('.list').append("<li><a href='#'>"A"</a><a class='A'></a></li>");
    $('.list').listview().listview('refresh');
  });

I'm using dynamically added elements to add more dynamically added elements :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44451/discussion-between-omar-and-benjamin-anderson)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are attaching the event to the document and then unbinding it in the next line. So your binding on `A` is lost when you turn off `tap` on document and bind again on document for b.

Try:

```
$(document).off("tap");
$(document).on("tap", "#A", function() {
    alert('Hi');
});

$(document).on("tap", "#B", function () {
    alert('Bye');
});
```

Also you can chain it though as well just to avoid creating jquery object again and again.

```
$(document).off("tap")
  .on("tap", "#A", function() {
    alert('Hi');
}).on("tap", "#B", function () {
    alert('Bye');
});
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. I can't accept the answer quite yet but I will here in about 5mins when I can.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @BenjaminAnderson Is both A and B ultimately calling the same function?

Comment: No. They are calling different functions and are also using a $(this) selector to access info from either A or B.